# How much power loss is included when charging a cell phone via inverter?

Tags: power-supply

So I know my power loss with my inverter is around 20 percent, and with the phone rectifier it's basically nothing but still measurable. I'm trying to figure up the actual wattage used to charge 2 cell phones from an inverter 120v 60hz modified sw. I can say it's the wattage of the two chargers but that's not accounting for the 20 percent loss.

Comment: "phone rectifier": It's a switch-mode power supply, not a rectifier. "basically nothing but still measurable": don't know what phone charger you have, but all that I have are not really high-efficiency.

Comment: Depends on the inverter

Answer (score 0):

You can't go by the wattage – that's just a peak wattage, and that isn't relevant to efficiency.

Since efficiency of power supplies, no matter whether step-up (your "inverter") or step-down (your phone charger) is not a constant but depends on the load, you either need a very good model of your electronics (which can't exist for a phone, because you can't know a priori in which state the battery is, and what the phone does during charging), or you'll need to measure.

So, measure.

Comment: I forget the basic math sometimes, I figured it up. There's a 20 percent loss with my inverter. You lose 20 percent vs connecting it directly to your dc source via step down regulator. I was trying to explain this.

Comment: @TIIME i don't get your point?